# Realizar petición Openweather para los próximos 5 días

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

Estoy tratando de realizar una petición a openweather con retrofit para que me devuelva la predicción de los próximos 5 días, he conseguido que me devuelva las ciudades del mundo al realizar la búsqueda, pero ahora me piden que realice la predicción de los próximos 5 días haciendo click en esa misma ciudad, se supone que pasando el id de la ciudad en la que hago click, el problema es que no sé cómo pasar ese id por la siguiente petición ni se muy bien dónde poner el código para que esto ocurra.

Por el momento he conseguido dentro del fragment:

```
//Fragment recycler view predicciones
Retrofit retrofit = ((RetrofitApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getRetrofitOpenWeather();

final IOpenWeatherAPI service = retrofit.create(IOpenWeatherAPI.class);

final Call<RootPredicciones> call = service.getPredicciones(latitud, longitud);

call.enqueue(new Callback<RootPredicciones>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<RootPredicciones> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            RootPredicciones listPrediccion = response.body();

            recyclerView.setAdapter(new ListPrediccionAdapter(listPrediccion, mListener, getActivity()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error onFailure: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Y la petición en la interface:

```
 @GET("/data/2.5/forecast")
    Call<Root> getPredicciones(@Query("lat") String latitud, @Query("lon") String longitud);
```